# real link in html-mode emacs

Tags: html, emacs

emacs has taken my image src text and made it followable. how do I turn that off so I just have plain text.

```
<img src="index_new_menus_files/menu_bg_2.gif" alt="" border="0" height="55" width="150">
```

should be

```
<img src="images/menu_bg_2.gif" alt="" border="0" height="55" width="150">
```

the first is clickable and opens the image file, the second is the actual text which is what I want to see.

how do I turn this off without turning off html-mode?

edit #1
mlinks-mode is what is doing it, and it was firefox that changed the image paths when I "saved page as"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question.  You appear to be saying that Emacs is displaying `src="index_new_menus_files/menu_bg_2.gif"` in the buffer, but is saving it as `src="images/menu_bg_2.gif"`.  But I find that hard to believe.

In Firefox, when you Save Page As... "Web page, complete", it changes all the `<img>` tags to link to the *pagename*`_files` directory.  Once it's done that, there's no way for Emacs to know what the original link looked like.  You'd have to Save Page As... "Web page, HTML only" to prevent Firefox from changing all the links.  That has nothing to do with Emacs.